# Using gl_ClipDistance in a geometry-shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I'm trying to make use of `gl_ClipDistance` within a geometry-shader but I cannot get it to work.
My shader runs within a transform-feedback recording and I want to cut triangles against 4 clipping planes.

I read the GLSL lang spec and tried to find a complete example (didn't find any). Here is what my shader looks like (shortened):

```
#version 150
#extension GL_EXT_gpu_shader4 : require
#extension GL_EXT_geometry_shader4 : require
#pragma optionNV unroll all

layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=3) out;

in vec4 io_Position[];
in vec3 io_Normal[];
in vec4 io_MultiTexCoord0[];
in vec4 io_MultiTexCoord1[];

...    

out vec3 out_Position;
out vec3 out_Normal;
out vec2 out_MultiTexCoord0;
out vec2 out_MultiTexCoord1;
out float gl_ClipDistance[4]; // do I have to initialize it like that?

void main()
{
  ...

  // emit three vertices
  for (int v=0; v<gl_VerticesIn; v++) 
  {   
      out_Position = io_Position[v].xyz;
      out_Normal = io_Normal[v];
      out_MultiTexCoord0 = io_MultiTexCoord0[v].xy;
      out_MultiTexCoord1 = io_MultiTexCoord1[v].xy;

      // calculate clip distances     
      for(int c=0; c<4; c++) 
      {  
        // From spec: The clip distances will be linearly interpolated across the
        // primitive and the portion of the primitive with interpolated distances less than 
        gl_ClipDistance[c] = distancePlane(clipPlanes[c], triWorldPos[v]);
      }     

      EmitVertex();
  }

  // create triangle
  EndPrimitive();  
}
```

Before I start the transform-feedback I set:

```
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE1);
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE2);
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE3);
```

My `planeDistance()` returns positive and negative distances depending on which side the vertex lies. I even tried writing negative values to some of the `gl_ClipDistance[c]`, but it doesn't clip anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Transform feedback output happens immediately after the geometry shader, before the viewport transform or clipping against the frustum or custom clip planes. You can't get post-clipping triangles into a transform-output buffer.

If you're just using this buffer to feed back into the pipeline for later rendering, you can do the clipping at that point. Or, if you need clipped triangles in the transform feedback buffer, you can try doing the clipping yourself in the geometry shader (matching GL's built-in clipping exactly would be difficult, if that's a requirement).

Comment: Ah...this is something I was never quite sure of. I assumed clipping would still be performed in transform-feedback. This: [ http://wiki.delphigl.com/index.php/Transform-Feedback ] gives a good overview. I will try to record the clipDistance and apply it in the actuall rendering.